# WordPress - Possible For Publish_Post Hook To Finish After Callback Finishes?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, hook, publish

I have written a function that operates as a callback for the hook `publish_post`, its purpose is to check if the post has a featured image, if it does not it looks for the first image attached within that post and does some image manipulation, then sets this new manipulated image as the featured image.

I know the bit of code that looks for the first attached image works, because it's also how the slider works on the website.

When used in the `publish_post` hook, however, it does not grab the first image attached to the post, but returns the default path indicating that no image was found.

Is it possible that the new post has not been completely stored in the database by the time the `publish_post` hook is called, and if so, is there a hook that exists that executes AFTER the post has been fully published?

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_insert_post` hook passes post ID and post data (see [`wp_publish_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post)):

```
do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post->ID, $post, true );
```

Comment: So to clarify, I want the publishing of the post to occur naturally on the admin's side, I'd rather stay away from manually inserting posts.